# strange error in glassfish log regarding jpa connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I get this error:

```
Error connecting to server localhost on port 1'527 with message Connection refused
```

detailed:

```
cannot Deploy TestGlassFish
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [TestGlassFish] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1'527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I have:

- j2ee application which works generally.
- added capability of jpa in my project by:

adding persistence.xml to the META-INF Folder and I have prooved, that this persistence.xml is recognized.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <!-- <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">-->
    <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence">-->
        <!-- <class>javax.persistence.EntityManager</class>-->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

- I have a running mysql database on port 3306.
- I have the corresponding sql jdbc driver added through maven dependency.

Why does my app try to connect to 1527 and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Solved for me: JPA runs in a J2ee environment so the datasource has to be defined as a JNDI Datasource in the application Server. Adding the <jta-data-source> in persistence.xml the connection was established.

Comment: could you please give more details on how you solved your problem: I'm facing the same problem